# How to do String formatting on String variable whose value spans multiple lines?

Tags: java

I am storing multiple string variable value in one string variable using for loop as follows

```
String arr[]={"value1","value2","value3","value4"};
String temp="";
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    temp=temp+arr[i]+"\n";
}
```

When I do String formatting on temp

```
String formattemp=String.format("%30s",temp);
System.out.println(formattemp);
```

output is:

```
  value1
value2
value3
value4
```

This is because I think temp variable has 28 characters including end of line
Therefor output is padded to left

But I want to display output as:

```
  value1
  value2
  value3
  value4
```

How can I do this?
Could anyone please help me on this

Thank You

Comment: Try `System.out.println(formattemp.trim());`
`

Comment: Please format your question properly and add proper code snippet

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do as half of your code seems to be missing and the two outputs look exactly the same to me.

Comment: I Will edit question and let you know

Comment: Why not doing the `System.out.printf("%30s%n", arr[i])`inside the loop?

Comment: Hi SubOptimal, 
I tried doing that on array it works for array. But I want to do it for string variable whose value spans multiple lines.

Comment: Hmm you may have to split the variable value at the linebreaks.

Comment: Something like `String[] result = foo.split( "\n" );` and then do the array loop as SubOptimal recommended.

Comment: Hi Rhayene, This worked for me Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String arr[]={"value1","value2","value3","value4"};

    for (String temp : arr) {
    System.out.printf ("%30s%n", temp);

}
```

The `for ( String s : array)` can be used to loop through the whole array, executing code inside the `for loop`for each element stored in the array. And it also does what you want, it converts the value in array to String.

Converting the array to string and then printing it is a inefficient design in my opinon

Comment: Hi The Law, Actually when I fetch value in String variable then its value spans multiple line. I don't want to do it on array, because in my original program there is no for loop. There is this String variable containing value same as "temp" variable

Comment: How long is supposed to be one line printed from that string? You could use  `String formattemp = temp.subString(int beginIndex, int endIndex) ` to create new string from the original string and print it on the line and loop it inside the  `while ` until you get to the end of the original string